# How to sort and compress reference numbers in FLDAUTH.cls or document classes other that elsarticle.cls?

Tags: hyperref

The option `sort&compress` does not work simultaneously with `hyperref` in `FLDAUTH.cls`. As a result, by eliminating `sort&compress`, I cannot compress the reference numbers. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use `\usepackage{cite}` instead of the option `sort&compress`. It seems that the combinations of `sort&compress` and `hyperref` works with `elsarticle.cls` and not necessarily with other document classes.